# Is there any way to remove or alter the branding message on confirmation emails?

Tags: cognito-forms

At the foot of the confirmation email it says:

> You are receiving this email because you completed a transaction
>   with....`(insert company name here)`

Is there any way to remove this or alter the wording?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

We currently do not offer the ability to remove the branding message at the bottom of the email. This is something that we do plan to let users have control over in the future once we release our Payment Plans. You can follow our progress for the Payment Plans feature over on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/URksRdbH).

Comment: This wording is removed in confirmation emails sent for our paid plans.  Cognito Forms is never mentioned in confirmation emails and you can now customize both the name and email address of the sender if your organization name is not who the email should be sent from.